# error 403 in htmlunit scraping although it’s manually opening

Tags: java, htmlunit, http-status-code-403, htmlunit-driver

I’m trying to use html_unit 1.14 for scraping on fake proxy. It gives me **(error 403**), although it’s opened manually on the browser.

What could be the reason and how to detect it?

Comment: Where’s your code that doesn’t work?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 (optional) : upgrade to v2.18 or newer

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
</dependency>
```

Step 2 (mandatory) :

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(yourbrowser);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

Comment: How do you know OP already doesn’t have what you’re suggesting?